# Como pegar os dados de um campo especifico em um XML,com Nodejs,e depois salva-lo no banco Mongo

Tags: json, node.js, xml, mongodb, mongoose

Na resposta de uma API,me traz um XML,porém eu preciso capturar apenas alguns campos específicos e salvar no meu banco de dados **MongoDB** com o pacote **Mongoose**,usando **Nodejs** e **Axios**.

Minha resposta XML vem assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<session>
    <id>1b6b0de9dd6549ebb5e0142ddd95facd</id>
</session>
```

Essa é a parte do meu código que retorna/imprime a resposta XML acima:

```
 .then(function(response) {
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      //return res.json(response.data);

      const sessionId = response.data;

      const session_Id = new MyModelMongo({

        sessionId,

      });

      session_Id.save();
      //return res.json(session_Id.id);
      //return res.json(session_Id.sessionId);
      return res.send(response.data);


    })
```

Preciso retornar/imprimir apenas um campo específico,o **id** que esta dentro de **session**,que estão presentes na resposta da API em XML, e salva-lo no banco de dados.Eu nunca trabalhei com xml e estou com dificuldades de retornar e salvar apenas esse campo **id**.

Desde já grato!

Comment: Acredito que vou ter que baixar um pacote para isso,durante minhas pesquisas eu não encontrei como forma nativa do JS/Node para fazer isso.Depois volto com o resultado!

Comment: Claro,porém a princípio notei que você salvou a resposta estática no const = entrada,porém como se trata de um retorno da API,essa campo id,será diferente a cada nova resposta.Estou pensando aqui,acho que com uma pequena alteração funcionaria.Vou tentar! OBG!

Comment: É sim,com uma pequena alteração.Mas tarde irei testar e volto com os resultados.Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Realmente com seu exemplo consegui imprimir cada id dinâmico conforme cada resposta.Porém eu preciso salvar esse dado no meu banco mongo.E não conseguir isolar apenas o match[1] em uma variável para posteriormente salvar no banco,ainda salvo o xml completo como antes.Poderia me ajudar nesse ponto? Notei que ao imprimir o match[1] ele responde corretamente o id,porém falta tratar e salvar no banco.

Comment: Editei minha resposta

Comment: Perfeito abençoado! Eu sempre fui péssimo com regex,e vou ter que dar uma relida sobre ele aqui.Cara no geral ajudou muito,consegui fazer todo processo perfeitamente,muitas pessoas me aconselharam a instalar um pacote do node,porém eu sabia que uma pessoa inteligente poderia resolver.Valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso queira utilizar uma solução que utiliza expressão regular, pode tentar o seguinte código:

```
const entrada = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<session>
    <id>1b6b0de9dd6549ebb5e0142ddd95facd</id>
</session>`
const regexexp = /<id>(.+?)<\/id>/
const match = regexexp.exec(entrada)
```

Utilizando essa expressão regular, ela vai capturar 2 expressões possíveis para a entrada passada. Deixando os valores disponíveis em um array. Sendo possível recuperar 2 valores.

```
console.log(match[0])
//"<id>1b6b0de9dd6549ebb5e0142ddd95facd</id>"
console.log(match[1])
//"1b6b0de9dd6549ebb5e0142ddd95facd"
```

Você pode aprender mais sobre como funciona a [função match aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Para implementar esta funcionalidade em seu código, seria alguma coisa como:

```
.then(function(response) {
  const regexexp = /<id>(.+?)<\/id>/
  const sessionMatch = regexexp.exec(response.data)
  const sessionId = sessionMatch[1];

  const session_Id = new MyModelMongo({

    sessionId,

  });

  session_Id.save();
  return res.send(response.data);
})
```

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

#### alternativa...

Para quem quiser evitar usar regex e busca uma solução alternativa utilizando alguma biblioteca específica para isso, podemos usar no Node.JS o [`fast-xml-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser):

Instalação:

```
npm install fast-xml-parser
```

Uso:

```
const parser = require('fast-xml-parser');

const jsonObj = parser.parse(response); // "entrada"
```

Agora podemos acessar propriedades como em um objeto JavaScript:

```js
console.log(jsonObj.session.id); // 1b6b0de9dd6549ebb5e0142ddd95facd
```

Exemplo de usando uma CDN e o XML da pergunta como exemplo:

```js
const response =
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>' +
  '<session>' +
  '<id>1b6b0de9dd6549ebb5e0142ddd95facd</id>' +
  '</session>';

const responseObj = parser.parse(response);

console.log('dados do "response":', responseObj);
console.log('ID da "session":', responseObj.session.id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fast-xml-parser/3.18.0/parser.min.js"></script>
```